# Network profile missing null

Tags: powershell, networking, null, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to retrive nics from multiple Vms, for loop is created for nic such as it will check if the vm has multiple nic assosiated with it, if yes then it will set it as primary.if the vm is having single nic then it will just attach the nic while creating VM, when the code is run it gives error network profile missing.

```
$vmnic = $vmnic.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfacesID
foreach($nic in $vmnic)
{
if($nic.IndexOf($vmnic) -eq 0)
{
$vmnew = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmnic -Id $nic -Primary
}
else
{
$vmnew = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmnic -Id $nic
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for above for loop nics

```
    if($vmoldnic.Count -gt 1) {

    foreach($nic in $vmoldnic)
    {        
        if($nic.Primary -eq $true)
        {          
           $vmnew = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmnew -Id $nic.Id -Primary
        }
        else
        {           
           $vmnew = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmnew -Id $nic.Id
        }
    }
```